# Plugin shortcut, incompatibilidade

Tags: javascript, jquery

Faço uso de um plugin que ativa as teclas de atalho:

> http://www.stepanreznikov.com/js-shortcuts/

Só que esse plugin roda somente nas versões antigas do jQuery.

Gostaria que ele funcionasse na ultima versão do jQuery 2.1.4.

Alguém se habilita a fazer as alterações/ajustes no GitHub deste projeto ou me indicar um plugin que funcione na ultima versão do jQuery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recomendo o [KeyboardJS](https://github.com/RobertWHurst/KeyboardJS). Já usei em alguns projetos e ele é bem simples de utilizar. Caso não goste dessa biblioteca ou não se adeque a ela, recomendo essa outra aqui [Ḿousetrap](https://craig.is/killing/mice)

Comment: Obrigado Armando, eu tinha esquecido de aceitar a resposta, desculpe!